# RSolr::Error::Http in PostsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot-rails

I had it working in develoment mode but when I messed around to get it in production mode something went wrong. I've been at this for 4 hours. I uninstalled the gems sunspot_rails and sunspot_solr and deleted all the files associated with them and did it again and I still get the same error, I don't understand it

error:

```
RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found Error: NOT_FOUND Request Data: "fq=type%3APost&start=0&rows=10&q=%2A%3A%2A" Backtrace: /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:283:in `adapt_response' /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute' /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive' /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation' /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument' /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument' /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument' /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation' (eval):2:in `post' /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sunspot-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/search/abstract_search.rb:45:in `execute' /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:344:in `solr_execute_search'
```

extracted source:

```
 def index
@search = Post.search do   <======this is highlighted
  fulltext params[:search]
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by adding

```
 url: http://localhost:8982/solr/development
```

to sunspot.yml